# Error in creating changes map in MOLUSCE

Tags: qgis, molusce

I'm using QGIS 2.8.9 Wein and the plug-in MOLUSCE(ver. 3. 0. 13).
Now I'm trying to create a change map, but get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../.qgis2/python/plugins\molusce\moluscedialog.py", line 479, in changeMapDone
    self.inputs["changeMap"].save(self.inputs["changeMapName"])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I'm new to QGIS and not familiar with Python.

So I wonder that "NoneType" something means that the preprocessing was wrong... but not sure.

EDIT: Updated to QGIS 2.18, but the same issue persists.

Comment: If you just started using QGIS, why install such an old version? MOLUSCE 3.0.13 is compatible with QGIS 2.18.

Comment: I misunderstood that this is the latest QGIS 2.XX for some reason... I've installed  2.18. Thanks!

Comment: Did that fix the problem, or does it persist even with version 2.18?

Comment: I tried the process in order and it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way of solving the issue!
I'd continued searching for it, and reached the following github comment:

https://github.com/nextgis/molusce/issues/9#issuecomment-307839416

The rasters have 3 to 4-digit codes used to classify land use types.
I used r.reclass to change the codes into smaller numbers and I could make a change map.

Thanks.